Entropy change in isothermal reversible expansion
So, this question is of JEE Mains 2023 exams. 
One mole of an ideal gas at $350K$ is in a $2.0L$ vessel of thermally conducting walls, which are in contact with the surroundings. It undergoes isothermal reversible expansion from $2.0L$ to $3.0L$ against a constant pressure of $4$atm. The change in entropy of the surroundings (ΔS) is $JK^{-1}$ (Nearest integer) Given: $R = 8.314 J K^{-1}mol^{-1}$ . 
I know that the change in entropy of surroundings is negative of change in entropy of system in this case since the process is reversible. But there are a few problems. First of all we know that for an ideal gas, $$ PV = nRT$$ Now it is given that Pressure is constant and process is isothermal. So, since $P, R,T$ are constants then it simply means that $V$ is proportional to n. Volume has increased so the number of moles must increase but that doesn't seem to be the case here. Second thing is we know that for reversible process $$ \Delta S=n R ln \left( \frac {V2}{V1} \right)$$ Hence the entropy change is $$ 8.314 ln(\frac 32)  = 8.314 (0.405) = 3.36(apx) $$ Now if we try to find the same by the formula $$ΔS=\frac {q_{rev}}T$$
We know that $U$ is $0$ since process is isothermal , so by first law of thermodynamics $$q = -w$$. Since pressure is constant, $$ w = -P_{ext} \Delta V  = -4(1) = -4atmL = -404J(apx)$$
So $q$ is $404J$. Now, $$ΔS=\frac {q_{rev}}T =404/350 = 1.153(apx)$$  Thus we get two different answer for the same question. How can this happen?

Guides for formatting of chemical/mathematical formulas/expressions/equations: Basics / Detailed / Upright vs Italics / Math SE Mathjax tutorial
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

It doesn’t seem that such a reversible process is possible.

@ChetMiller I also think so

This is too long for a comment, so I'll give it as a partial answer. I agree it cannot be reversible.
First calculate, using the ideal gas formula, the initial pressure of the gas at 350 K and 2.0 L, which comes out to be 1455 kPa or 14.4 atm. So then we are told that it expands against a constant pressure of 4 atm. So we picture some sort of piston with a lock mechanism that holds the pressure at 14,4 atm, and is suddenly released, after which the pressure is held at 4 atm until the volume is 3.0 L, then the lock is again applied.
This sudden change means it cannot be a reversible process - in a reversible isothermal expansion, the external pressure would be slowly changed from 14.4 atm to a final value compatible with 3.0 L at 350 K, i.e. 9.6 atm, and would always be equal to the pressure of the gas.
